# DTD's Mixed content model

Tags: xml, dtd

Say I have something like this

```
       <offor>Ubuntu Juju is all that you need 
      <charm Id="lisp" \>.</offor><offor>This one is the name thing</offor>
```

This is my DTD

```
       <!ELEMENT offor (#PCDATA, charm?) >
      <!ELEMENT charm EMPTY>
      <!ATTLIST id ID #REQUIRED>
```

Could someone assist me here? My DTD is not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with both your XML and your DTD:

1. You don't have a root element. I added `<doc>` in my example below.
2. You used a backslash (`\`) instead of a forward slash (`/`) when you closed `charm`.
3. When you have [mixed content](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-mixed-content), you can't specify the order of `#PCDATA` and the child elements using `,`. You have to use `|` (or) and an asterisk (`*`).
4. In your `ATTLIST` declaration, you forgot to add the name of the element the attribute(s) are declared for.
5. The `Id` attribute in the XML does not match the case of the attribute name `id` in the DTD.

Here's an example of an updated XML and DTD. The DTD is in the internal subset, but would work just as well if used as an external DTD.

```
<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ELEMENT doc (offor+)>
<!ELEMENT offor (#PCDATA|charm)* >
<!ELEMENT charm EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST charm 
          id ID #REQUIRED>
]>
<doc>
  <offor>Ubuntu Juju is all that you need 
    <charm id="lisp"/>.</offor><offor>This one is the name thing</offor>
</doc>
```

Comment: Excellent answer. I did not know that you could not specify the order for mixed content. Great explications.